# Combinatorics - How many ways to arrange 4 different dumbbells in 7 different drawers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many ways to arrange 4 different dumbbells in 7 different drawers?

**My attempt:**

There are 5 cases to arrange 4 different dumbbells call them {A,B,C,D}

**1 2 3 4 5 6 7 : Drawers**

2  2  0  0  0  0   0 (1

3 0 1 0 0 0 0 (2

4 0 0 0 0 0 0 (3

2 1 1 0 0 0 0 (4

1 1 1 1 0 0 0 (5

1. To distribute 2 sets each over 7 different drawers so we have
   P(7,2)*C(4,2) when P(7,2) number of ways to choose a place for each 2 sets of size 2 and (4,2) to arrange the dumbbells

*-Same idea for the followings*

2. P(7,2) * C(4,3)
3. P(7,1)*C(4,4)
4. P(7,3)*C(4,2)
5. P(7,4) * C(4,3)*C(3,2)C(2,1)

And at the end we sum all the cases 1+2+3+4+5

Would that be a correct solution to the question?

***Subside question** (for whoever wants to answer) : same question but how to arrange them when the heaviest dumbbell =A and lightest =D can't be in the same drawer?

I thought about cases (1+2+3+4+5) - (All the possibilities when A and D are together)

To count A and D as one body so we will only have 3 cases when

**1 2 3 4 5 6 7 : Drawers**

1  2  0  0  0  0   0 (1

1 1 1 0 0 0 0 (2

3 0 0 0 0 0 0 (3

So at end the cases from first question (1+2+3+4+5) - (1+2+3) = possibilities of A and D not together?

Comment: "arranging in drawers" Does order within a drawer matter?

Comment: If order within a drawer matters, then consider rearranging the following string:  `A B C D | | | | | |`.  If order within a drawer doesn't matter, then simply choose which drawer each dumbbell goes into individually.

Comment: @JMoravitz no order within the drawer doesn't matter if it was ABC or CBA it's the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each (distinguishable) dumbell can be placed in one of seven (distinguishable) drawers, and hence the number is $7^4$.

The first dumbell can be put in drawer 1, or drawer 2, or ... 7.

The second dumbell can be put in drawer 1, or drawer 2, or ... 7, independent of the first.

Thus there are $7^2 = 7 \times 7 = 49$ possible distributions of the two distinguishable dumbells.

The third dumbell...

Comment: Could you give me a small example to elaborate more please?